# Propriedade do Tablix no Report Builder 3.0

Tags: relatório, reporting-services

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma propriedade no Tablix que me informe se o campo está no estado `expanded` ou `collapsed`?

Estou querendo exibir algumas informações em uma coluna **apenas se** o campo da esquerda estiver expandido. A ideia seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
=IIF(Fields!DivisionT.Expanded = False, "", First(Fields!QtdeApr.Value))
```

Conhecem alguma maneira de fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri a maneira de fazer o que quero. Não preciso usar nenhum recurso de expressões, basta usar a propriedade de visibilidade do campo em questão.

Relembrando que: "*Estou querendo exibir algumas informações em uma coluna **apenas se** o campo da esquerda estiver expandido.*" **A solução é**:

---

- Clique com o botão direito do mouse no campo da direita (campo que deve aparecer **apenas se**...).
- Selecione a propriedade *Visibility*
- Selecione *Hide*
- Marque a opção: "*Display can be toggled by this report item:*"
- Na Combo Box abaixo dessa opção selecione o nome do campo da direita.

---

O resultado disso é que o campo da direita sempre iniciará oculto mas, quando o campo da esquerda for expandido, o da direita aparecerá.

Resultado obtido!